# Vue and Vuex making Axios operation inside store module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm writing a app in Vue using Vuex as state management.

To CRUD operation on data I use Axios.

Problem is when I for ex.

> post something to my MongoDB database with Express server

(both are temporary will be replaced later) the state in Vuex is not touched and component will not auto rerender with new data. 
I need to refresh page.

But with example like this one below I can re-render the component with mutations on state, but it's not the perfect and preferred way for me.

Is there any way to "touch" the state to re-render component when I do post/delete/update? Not looking for hard refresh or placing fetchData() inside updated() lifehook, bcs component is asking like every 100ms for new data.

Below code is not mine but its super straight to get what it's doing to what I want.

```
// Tasks module
import axios from 'axios';

const resource_uri = "http://localhost:3000/task/";

const state = {
    tasks: []
};

const getters = {
    allTasks: state => state.tasks
};

const actions = {
    async fetchTasks({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(resource_uri);    
        commit('setTasks', response.data);
    },
    async addTask( { commit }, task) {
        const response = await axios.post(resource_uri, task);
        commit('newTask', response.data);
    },
    async updateTask( { commit }, task) {
        const response = await axios.put(`${resource_uri}${task.id}`, task);
        commit('updTask', response.data);
    },
    async removeTask( { commit }, task) {
        const response = await axios.delete(`${resource_uri}${task.id}`);
        commit('deleteTask', task);
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setTasks: (state, tasks) => state.tasks = tasks,
    newTask: (state, task) => state.tasks.unshift(task),
    updTask: (state, updatedTask) => {
        const index = state.tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === updatedTask.id);
        if(index !== -1) {
            state.tasks.splice(index, 1, updatedTask);
        }        
    },
    deleteTask: (state, task) => state.tasks = state.tasks.filter(t => task.id !== t.id),
};

export default {
    state, getters, actions, mutations
}
```

Edit: 
Right now it look like this:

- axios.get(task)
- commit and "save" data in `state.tasks[]`
- when `axios.post(data)` server gets data and save `state.tasks[]` stay
  untouched so component not re-rendering with new data

How to re-render component when data has been saved in database but without touching `state.tasks[]` with mutations making changes with array methods.

Comment: is the problem only occurred when you "post"?

Comment: @Evan with delete/update/post too, with everything what axios can do. Mostly I want to get rid of those mutations newTask(), updTask(), deleteTask(). setTasks() is important so no doubt is needed here

Comment: It's so unclear what you want to achieve. What do you mean by `re-render`? You should have `reactive data` in your components.

Comment: If you use `vuex` then use `computed` properties in your component and they will always be actual when your `state` changes.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov yes it's unclear. Short story. Do I always need to do operation on state.tasks[] to update state. Like state.tasks.push(newTask) or is there any other way to update state after posting/deleting/updating. It will be inconvenient to do such operations when my state.tasks[] will have tons of nested arrays.

Comment: Yes, you should update your `state` because that should be the only one origin of your data in a component.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov is it possible to call mutation inside action, where I post/delete/update, to get fresh data from database and update state?

Comment: Yes, but you also can do mutation correctly. Do not `shift, unShift, splice` array in your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presented code you are not getting refreshed data in your component because you're doing mutations not correctly. See the code below:

```
 const mutations = {
    setTasks: (state, tasks) => state.tasks = tasks,
    newTask: (state, task) => state.tasks = [task, ...state.tasks],
    updTask: (state, updatedTask) => {
        let tasks = [...state.tasks];
        const index = tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === updatedTask.id);
        if(index !== -1) {
            tasks.splice(index, 1, updatedTask);
        }
        state.tasks = [...tasks];
    },
    // deleteTask should work correctly
    deleteTask: (state, task) => state.tasks = state.tasks.filter(t => task.id !== t.id),
};
```

**Update**

As you mentioned in the comments that your data can be more complex with nested arrays and so on - I suggest to replace the logic to the server. You should do everything on your server (`update`, `push`, `delete`) and then just return updated `tasks`. Then you can avoid using mutations exept one: `setTasks`.

Comment: Thanks for "close" solution. But what if I will have array of nested elements like 10 arrays deep. This solution will not work imo.

Comment: Do whatever you need with the copy of that array and then jsut assign its value to the `state.tasks`.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now! It looks super easy after you pointed the direction!